# 'The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply()' error all of a sudden

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, uiapplicationdelegate

I recently reverted back to a previous version of my app through my Time Capsule backup, and everything is working as it should be with the exception of one thing. When I try to use the watch extension for my app, it never receives a reply from the parent application. I haven't changed any code, but it doesn't work no matter what. Even if I just send an empty request and a simple string back, I get the same error:

> The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply()

This is (the simplified version of) my code:

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(["test": "test"]) { userInfo, error in
        println("User Info: \(userInfo)")
        println("Error: \(error)")
    }        
}
```

Delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
    let favouritesArrayDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("favourites")!

    if let pfqueryRequest: AnyObject = (userInfo as? [String: AnyObject])?["parkName"] {
    } else {
        let taskID = beginBackgroundUpdateTask()

        reply(["Success": "Success"])

        endBackgroundUpdateTask(taskID)
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Hover your mouse over the xcode tag you used and read when that tag is appropriate. Considering your question has nothing (even remotely) to do with xcode, please edit your question to remove that tag. Invalid use of tags is distracting to the site.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to call the watch's reply function immediately. You can't wait until an async function completes. By then the watch has given up and decided the phone isn't going to reply. I can't find the statement to that effect in Apple's docs any more, but I do remember reading it.

Comment: Even if I call it right away, I still get the same error. Also, this used to work absolutely fine and I have no idea what has changed since then.

Comment: Don't read too much into that. Code that should not work sometimes works anyway, and then Apple changes something and it stops working. Did you update your iOS or Xcode in the meantime?

Comment: Nope. It worked fine for weeks up until 2 days ago. Between now and then I changed the bundle identifiers for the app, extension and watch app however it caused some issues, so that's why I have reverted back to an older backup.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not call the replyBlock in the first if block (before the else). Might that be the code path that you see the error log for?

Comment: That isn't the full code. I just removed the unnecessary code from the question. Even if I can the replyBlock immediately, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! The line:

```
let favouritesArrayDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("favourites")!
```

Would crash if the array was empty. This was the first time I had tried the watch app with an empty array in the main app so that was why it had never occurred before.